# How To solve this pl sql oracle query?

Tags: plsql

3. Write a PL/SQL program using While Loop to display all DEPTNO,DNAME and LOC
   from DEPT table. Assuming the difference between two deptno is 10.

I am beginer and i am very confuse to solve this query please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    i            dept.deptno%type;   -- loop counter
  3    l_max_deptno dept.deptno%type;   -- upper limit
  4    l_dept_row   dept%rowtype;       -- will contain the whole DEPT table row
  5  begin
  6    -- MIN -> i (which will be the starting point); MAX -> l_max_deptno (which will be the end)
  7    select min(deptno), max(deptno)
  8      into i, l_max_deptno
  9      from dept;
 10
 11    while i <= l_max_deptno
 12    loop
 13      -- select the whole row into L_DEPT_ROW
 14      select *
 15        into l_dept_row
 16        from dept
 17        where deptno = i;
 18
 19      dbms_output.put_line(l_dept_row.deptno ||' - '||
 20                           l_dept_row.dname  ||' - '||
 21                           l_dept_row.loc);
 22      -- increment counter by 10 (because, as you said, the difference is 10)
 23      i := i + 10;
 24    end loop;
 25  end;
 26  /
10 - ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK
20 - RESEARCH - DALLAS
30 - SALES - CHICAGO
40 - OPERATIONS - BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do what you asked for, but bear in mind this is not the optimum way to do it. if your target is to train your self on the While loop in PLSQL, then here you go.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C_DEPTS
   IS
      SELECT DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC FROM DEPT;

   V_DEPTNO   VARCHAR2 (255);
   V_DNAME    VARCHAR2 (255);
   V_LOC      VARCHAR2 (255);
BEGIN
   OPEN C_DEPTS;

   FETCH C_DEPTS INTO V_DEPTNO, V_DNAME, V_LOC;

   WHILE C_DEPTS%FOUND
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DEPTNO = ' || V_DEPTNO);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DNAME = ' || V_DNAME);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('LOC = ' || V_LOC);

      FETCH C_DEPTS INTO V_DEPTNO, V_DNAME, V_LOC;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: here i have to use if else inside the loop rather than cursor i did this question by for loop but requirement is to solve by while here is my for loop solution i hope you convert it into while loop:  DECLARE
  x number := 0;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN (select * from dept) LOOP
   if i.deptno - x = 10 then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Department No : '|| i.deptno);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Department : '|| i.dname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Loc : '|| i.loc);
     x:=x+10;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: DECLARE
  x number := 0;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN (select * from dept) LOOP
   if i.deptno - x = 10 then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Department No : '|| i.deptno);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Department : '|| i.dname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Loc : '|| i.loc);
     x:=x+10;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;